# Bash-Scripting stderr and stdout

Tags: bash, stdout, stderr

I am new to bash-scripting & trying to understand how things work. It's all a bit strange..

I have two scripts. First this one:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
#name: stderrtest0.sh
echo "on ${1}: this is an error" >&2
echo "on ${1}: this is an info" >&1
echo "on ${1}: this is just text"
```

And this second script calls the first:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
#name: stderrtest1.sh
echo "invoking: stderrtest0.sh test1 >&2 ~output:"
./stderrtest0.sh test1 >&2

echo "invoking: stderrtest0.sh test2 >&1 ~output:"
./stderrtest0.sh test2 >&1

echo "invoking: stderrtest0.sh test3 2>&1 ~output:"
./stderrtest0.sh test3 2>&1

echo "invoking: stderrtest0.sh test4 1>&2 ~output:"
./stderrtest0.sh test4 1>&2

echo "invoking: stderrtest0.sh test5 ~output:"
./stderrtest0.sh test5
```

Here are my tests (*debian squeeze*) with the output:

**METATEST1)** invoke *stderrtest1.sh*

```
$ ./stderrtest1.sh
invoking: stderrtest0.sh test1 >&2 ~output:
on test1: this is an error
on test1: this is an info
on test1: this is just text
invoking: stderrtest0.sh test2 >&1 ~output:
on test2: this is an error
on test2: this is an info
on test2: this is just text
invoking: stderrtest0.sh test3 2>&1 ~output:
on test3: this is an error
on test3: this is an info
on test3: this is just text
invoking: stderrtest0.sh test4 1>&2 ~output:
on test4: this is an error
on test4: this is an info
on test4: this is just text
invoking: stderrtest0.sh test5 ~output:
on test5: this is an error
on test5: this is an info
on test5: this is just text
```

This is as I expect. Since by default `stderr` & `stdout` get sent to the terminal.

**METATEST2)** invoke *stderrtest1.sh* & redirect output to *out*

```
$ ./stderrtest1.sh >out
on test1: this is an error
on test1: this is an info
on test1: this is just text
on test2: this is an error
on test4: this is an error
on test4: this is an info
on test4: this is just text
on test5: this is an error

$ cat out
invoking: stderrtest0.sh test1 >&2 ~output:
invoking: stderrtest0.sh test2 >&1 ~output:
on test2: this is an info
on test2: this is just text
invoking: stderrtest0.sh test3 2>&1 ~output:
on test3: this is an error
on test3: this is an info
on test3: this is just text
invoking: stderrtest0.sh test4 1>&2 ~output:
invoking: stderrtest0.sh test5 ~output:
on test5: this is an info
on test5: this is just text
```

So here:

- all `stdout` gets sent to the file *out*
- all `stderr` gets sent to the terminal

This is not quite as I expect. I somehow thought everything might end up in *out*

**METATEST3)** invoke *stderrtest1.sh* & redirect `stdout` to *inf.out*

```
$ ./stderrtest1.sh 1>inf.out
on test1: this is an error
on test1: this is an info
on test1: this is just text
on test2: this is an error
on test4: this is an error
on test4: this is an info
on test4: this is just text
on test5: this is an error

$ cat inf.out
invoking: stderrtest0.sh test1 >&2 ~output:
invoking: stderrtest0.sh test2 >&1 ~output:
on test2: this is an info
on test2: this is just text
invoking: stderrtest0.sh test3 2>&1 ~output:
on test3: this is an error
on test3: this is an info
on test3: this is just text
invoking: stderrtest0.sh test4 1>&2 ~output:
invoking: stderrtest0.sh test5 ~output:
on test5: this is an info
on test5: this is just text
```

Results are identical to **METATEST2**:

- all `stdout` gets sent to the file *inf.out*
- all `stderr` gets sent to the terminal

Ok. Now I understand **METATEST2**. Redirecting without specification defaults to `stdout`.

**METATEST4)** invoke *stderrtest1.sh* & redirect `stderr` to *err.out*

```
$ ./stderrtest1.sh 2>err.out
invoking: stderrtest0.sh test1 >&2 ~output:
invoking: stderrtest0.sh test2 >&1 ~output:
on test2: this is an info
on test2: this is just text
invoking: stderrtest0.sh test3 2>&1 ~output:
on test3: this is an error
on test3: this is an info
on test3: this is just text
invoking: stderrtest0.sh test4 1>&2 ~output:
invoking: stderrtest0.sh test5 ~output:
on test5: this is an info
on test5: this is just text

$ cat err.out
on test1: this is an error
on test1: this is an info
on test1: this is just text
on test2: this is an error
on test4: this is an error
on test4: this is an info
on test4: this is just text
on test5: this is an error
```

And here I get confused. 
Because in **METATEST3 test1:**
all output from *stderrtest0.sh* gets redirected to `stderr` & so goes to the terminal but not to *inf.out*

And yet here in **METATEST4 test2:**
all output from *stderrtest1.sh* is being redirected to `stdout` ~BUT the `stderr` emitted by *stderrtest0.sh* somehow escapes ?

So this seems to imply:

- any/all output from some called program can be redirected into the caller's `stderr`.
- `stderr` output from some called program is not redirected into the caller's `stdout`.

Is this the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally the shell opens **two separate file descriptors** for stdout (1) and stderr (2). To redirect the output from a program sent to one to the other, it suffices to copy the FD from the other.

```
$ { echo "foo" >&2 ; } > /dev/null
foo
$ { echo "foo" 2>&1 >&2 ; } > /dev/null
$ { echo "foo" >&2 ; } > /dev/null 2>&1
$
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok! Thank you [Ignacio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20862/ignacio-vazquez-abrams) !

I think I was getting hung up on the s/h notation & the meaning of *redirection*. Understanding this in terms of copying a file descriptor makes it clearer to me. Because I'm a bit thick, I'm going to labour the point & maybe you can correct me if I'm still not getting it...

Firstly:
`echo "foo" >&2`

This does not redirect any/all of *echo*'s output to `stderr`; it is a s/h equivalent to `echo "foo" 1>&2`. It sets the `stdout` **FD** of the *echo* process to be the same as it's **FD** for `stderr`.

So then for:
`{ echo "foo" 2>&1 >&2 ; } > /dev/null`

Here, the `stderr` **FD** for the *echo* process is set to the `stdout` **FD**; then the `stdout` **FD** is set to the `stderr` **FD** ~accomplishing nothing since the new assignment is the same as the current value. And nothing gets to the terminal because the function's `stdout` **FD** is set to */dev/null*

And then for:
`{ echo "foo" >&2 ; } > /dev/null 2>&1`

Here the `stdout` **FD** of the *echo* process is set to the `stderr` **FD**. The function's `stdout` **FD** is set to */dev/null* and the function's `stderr` **FD** is set to the value of the `stdout` **FD** ~which is of course */dev/null*. &So nothing gets to the terminal.

Or to put it another way:

```
$ { echo "phew"; echo "bah" >&2; }
phew
bah
$ { echo "phew"; echo "bah" >&2; } 2>/dev/null
phew
$ { echo "phew"; echo "bah" >&2; } 1>/dev/null
bah
$ { echo "phew"; echo "bah" >&2; } 1>/dev/null 2>&1
$
```

I am a numpty.

&BTW I like how you use { a function } instead of having to write out whole silly scripts. Much neater ;)